# Java - while typing in a jTextArea, set focus to the corresponding jButton

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, jtextarea

So I have to create a jTextbox and a keyboard for an assignment. While I type, I need the corresponding jButton to change colour.

So currently, when I run, the focus is on the jTextbox, and I can type, but I can't set the focus to the button.

Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
private void aButtonKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
       aButton.setBackground(Color.red);           
    } 
}

private void aButtonKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        aButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }
}

private void sButtonKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
       sButton.setBackground(Color.red);           
    }
}

private void sButtonKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
       sButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);           
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why do you want the focus on the JButton.

Comment: maybe I am not wording myself correctly, I need to make the button change the color from red to gray every time it is pressed.

Comment: I see. So you need the JTextField for the inputs? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I mean, when you type on the JTextField, the JButton background would change?

Comment: Yeah exactly... So just like how I have the commentbox here, and I type in it, imagine if under it there was a "virtual keyboard" and as I type, the corresponding button would change colour onpress and return to the original colour onrelease

Comment: Andrew this is for an assignment for school. Last one of the term. I just want to get it over with.

Answer (score 2):

Have a common class which implements KeyListener and give that class to JButtons.

Have a Map to store Key Code and JButton

```
Map<Integer, JButton> keyCodeButtonMap = new HashMap<Integer, JButton>();
keyCodeButtonMap.put(KeyEvent.VK_A, aButton); // Example
```

Add all the KeyEvent Virtual Keys to the Map along with the correct button.

```
private void buttonKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    keyCodeButtonMap.get(evt.getKeyCode()).setBackground(Color.RED);
    keyCodeButtonMap.get(evt.getKeyCode()).setForeground(Color.RED);
}

private void buttonKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    keyCodeButtonMap.get(evt.getKeyCode()).setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    keyCodeButtonMap.get(evt.getKeyCode()).setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
}
```

This should Ideally work.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to try this and hopefully come back with "the right answer".

Comment: He probably doesn't want to change foreground, but is still a good one - +1.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you want to set focus to the `JButton` (or else you wont be able to type in `JTextArea`/`JTextField` etc), perhaps you want it to change its color and make it click when a certain character(s) are entered?

- When using Swing components rather use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as suggested by others.

Here is an example I made:

[image]

when <kbd>.</kbd> is pressed the button background will be changed to blue (and buttons method will called which to auto-inserts <kbd>SPACE</kbd> after '.'):

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JTextField jtf = new JTextField(15);
    final JButton button = new JButton("SPACE");

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                insertSpace();
            }
        });

        final Color defaultColor = button.getBackground();

        jtf.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD, 0, true), "period rel");
        jtf.getActionMap().put("period rel", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //button.doClick(); //I dont like this as it makes JBUtton look like its being clicked where as we want a color change
                insertSpace();
                button.setBackground(defaultColor);
            }
        });

        jtf.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD, 0), "period pressed");
        jtf.getActionMap().put("period pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }
        });

        frame.add(jtf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void insertSpace() {
        String s = jtf.getText();
        jtf.setText(s + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).
But if you really want KeyListener, try this.

```
    yourJtextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

       @Override
       public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
          if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A ){
             aButton.setBackground(yourColor);
          }
       }

       @Override
       public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
          aButton.setBackground(yourDefaultColor);
       }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am going to try this as well.

Comment: Because on his statement 'but I can't set the focus to the button.' he's probably doing the keyPressed event on a particular JButton, instead of a JTextField.